# stored procedure sql (Excel data to T-SQL)

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012, ssms

I need to set up a new company for automated data import. The utility has provided the data in a spreadsheet. (Image 1) 
[image]

Based on this data, I need to create a stored procedure that will identify the correct meter, if it exists, and perform either an insert or update to the monthly data table. For automated utility data import, I want to make sure I restrict everything to a particular utility company.

The steps are the following ( I am having a hard time converting this to SQL)
1- I just want  a script that identify the correct meter to see if it exists, basically check the Meter# column in the excel with the MeterNumber column in the Meters table.

2- The next step is perform either an insert or update to the MonthlyData table. This is a screen shot of all its columns.
[image]

3- Then I just want to make sure that I am restricting everything to the particular company which in this case Site1 since 2 different companies might have the same meter#. The UtilityCompany table contains 3 columns: ID, Name, UtilityType

I honestly do not know from where to get started, would anybody help me with the script? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You will want to:

- perform a Bulk Insert operation to take your data from the excel file into a staging table.
- write a query to select ALL rows for the corresponding utility company (notice I didn't see iterate over each row...). This select could be an update where you update an additional column to mark the row as an INSERT, or an UPDATE.
- Then the last step (2 parts), retrieve all of the rows that were marked as INSERT, and insert those into your table. Then grab all rows that were marked with an UPDATE, and update their corresponding values based on your matching criteria.